# How to calculate p-value significance of the correlation stats (2-tailed) for the weighted correlation using statsmodels DescrStatsW

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, p-value, weighted

I need some help regarding weighted correlation analysis in Python, using **from statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW** method.
I used SPSS in the past, and it would conveniently print **p-value** significance of the correlation stats, next to the correlation coefficients.

How to calculate **p-value** significance of the correlation stats (2-tailed), once we have the correlation coefficients?

Which of these methods below provides the **p-value** significance of the correlation probability (2-tailed) that I need?

- ttest_mean([value, alternative])
- ttost_mean(low, upp)
- var_ddof([ddof])
- zconfint_mean([alpha, alternative])
- ztest_mean([value, alternative])
- ztost_mean(low, upp)

### Background

I have a number of measurements made by different users, where some users made many of those and some users just a few. And I would like to perform a correlation analysis between **measurements** and **quality rating** for those measurements. As you can guess, I need to **weight** such a correlation.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame() # There are many more datapoints, but I reduced them for simplicity
df['measurements'] = [2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4.25, 3. , 3.5, 3.16, 4. , 3. , 3. , 3. , 3.33333333, 3.42857143]
df['quality'] = [-5.00000000e-02,  3.33333333e-01,  1.00000000e-01,  3.04166667e-01, -6.27500000e-01,  1.21666667e-01, -2.39304167e-01, -5.75000000e-01, -2.33333333e-01, -1.00000000e+00, -1.38777878e-17, -7.00000000e-01, -1.10714286e-01]
weights = [0.5, 1., 0.25, 0.125, 0.5, 0.5, 0.02, 0.5, 1., 1., 0.25, 0.33333333, 0.14285714]

from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import DescrStatsW
wcorr = DescrStatsW(df, weights=weights)
print(wcorr.corrcoef)

# Apparently this tests that each column has zero mean
# Which is not related to p-value significance at all
# tstat, ttest, df = wcorr.ttest_mean(0)
# print(ttest)
```

**Output: a weak correlation coefficient of 0.23 and how to get p-value significance?**

```
[[1.        0.2322971]
```

p.s. Also, why do I read that weights for DescrStatsW have to be '(weighted by the number of observations minus one)', why minus one per group cluster?

Comment: `wcorr.ttest_mean(0)` tests that each column has zero mean. It's not related to correlation.

Comment: Indeed, that was my guess that `wcorr.ttest_mean(0)` is for testing the zero-mean assumption, I will correct this in the OP. **But how then do I get the p-value significance of this weighted correlation?**